# Show that there are infinitely many integer solutions to the equation $x^3+y^5=z^7$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

> Show that there are infinitely many integers such that $$x^3+y^5=z^7$$ and where $x^3,y^5$ and $z^7$ are all non-zero and distinct.

The hint suggests to look at solutions of simultaneous equation

\begin{eqnarray*}
a \equiv 0 \mod 21 \qquad b \equiv 0 \mod 15 \\
a \equiv -1 \mod 5 \qquad b \equiv -1 \mod 7
\end{eqnarray*}

which we can directly read off the solutions $a=-21, b=-15$ which must be unique up to modulo $105$.

Then set $x=2^a3^b$, but I'm not really sure how this hint is useful in any way.

Comment: Have you considered Fermat's little theorem (or Fermat-Euler)?

Comment: Small hint: Write $a=84$, $b=90$ rather than negative numbers.

Comment: Right, then $x$ is an integer, and moreover there are infinitely many integers of the form $x=2^a 3^b$, so maybe each of these integers are solution to the equation. But how do I show this? Putting $y,z$ in the same form does not help, since $z^7$ grows much quicker than $x^3$ or $y^5$, and addition operation does not compensate for that gap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** From what you have got, see why you can write $$2^{84}3^{90}+2^{85}3^{90}=2^{84}3^{91}$$

Now can you see how to generate more solutions?

Comment: Wow, I find that magical. Then I guess I can proceed as what Jef Laga said - thanks!

Comment: You can multiply throughout by $k^{105}$ for any integer $k$ to get more solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If $(a,b,c)$ is a solution to your equation, then so is $(k^{35}a,k^{21}b,k^{15}c)$ for every integer $k$.

Now you only have to find one solution with the required conditions, which, considering your earlier efforts, shouldn't be too hard.