# Show that there are infinitely many solutions $x, y, z \in\mathbb N$ of the following equation $x^2 + y^3 = z^7.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, infinite-descent

Show that there are infinitely many solutions $x, y, z \in\mathbb N$ of the following equation
$x^2 + y^{3} = z^7$.

I am thinking about using proof by infinite descent, but I am not too sure how to start or how to show there are infinitely many solutions in the natural numbers.

Comment: @X0-user-0X I am studying elementary number theory and not calculus here, so this is not the right approach for my course.

Comment: Do you consider zero to be a natural number or not?

Comment: @StinkingBishop We assume zero is not a natural number.

Comment: How does this meet any quality standards?

Comment: Also, duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094061/prove-there-are-infinitely-many-x-y-z-positive-integers-satisfying-x5-y?rq=1), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333729/show-that-there-are-infinitely-many-integer-solutions-to-the-equation-x3y5-z?noredirect=1), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094061/prove-there-are-infinitely-many-x-y-z-positive-integers-satisfying-x5-y?noredirect=1), and at least a dozen more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $k\in \mathbb N$:
$$
((k^2+1)^3\cdot k)^2 + ((k^2+1)^2)^3
= (k^2+1)^6\cdot k^2 + (k^2+1)^6
=(k^2+1)^7
$$

(found by looking for a solution in the form $x=kt^3, y=t^2$)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

For every $a \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$(x,y,z)=(2213459a^{21}, 1414a^{14}, 65a^6)$$

is a solution.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

You see that
$$ (2^3)^2+(2^2)^3=2\cdot 64 = 2^7$$
is a solution.
So, one idea would to think, whats about powers of $2$.
Then we have
$$(2^a)^2+(2^b)^2=(2^c)^7.$$
In the example we furthermore have $x^2=y^3$, so we can also try this, which leads to
$$2^{7c}=2^{2a+1}=2^{3b+1}.$$
This is equivalent to $7c=2a+1=3b+1$.
For $a=3d$ and $b=2d$ we get $7c=6d+1$. Hence, it suffices to show that there are infinite $c,d\in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $7c-6d=1$. This is a typical linear Diophantine equation which can be solved by the usual procedure (or WolframAlpha) or you just see that $d=7n+1$ and $c=6n+1$ is a solution for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.
Back substitution gives you that
$$(2^{3(7n+1)},2^{2(7n+1)},2^{6n+1})$$
is a solution for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

This is a generalization of the answer by Zermelo-Fraenkel. Start with any one specific solution; Z-F identifies $8^2+4^3=2^7$, but it is possible to start with any other specific solution.

For all $k\in \mathbb N$, $(8k^{21})^2+(4k^{14})^3=(2k^{6})^7$

More generally, if $x,y,z$ is a solution, then $(x\cdot k^{21})^2+(y\cdot k^{14})^3=(z\cdot k^{6})^7$

Thus, if there are any solutions (and there is at least one), there are infinity many solutions.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1